# Calling return method from invoked method by reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Ok I do understand how Java Reflection works. But what I am doing is kinda different from what is shown on the Reflection tutorials. Now what I want below is to invoke a method that is returned by a invoking a method by using reflection.

```
   class Foo{
          private String str = "";

          public Foo(String str){
              str = this.str;
          }

          public void goo(){
            System.out.println(this.str);
          }
    }

    class Bar{
         public Foo met(String str){
              return new Foo(str); 
         }
    }

    class Hee{
         public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
                Class cls = Class.forName("Bar");
                Object obj = cls.newInstance();

                Class [] types = {String.class};
                String [] arr = {"hello"};
                Method method = cls.getMethod("met",types);

        Object target = method.invoke(obj, arr);

                target.goo(); //here where the error occurs
                // 123456
        }
    }
```

Now, I depend to much on my experience that my `method.invoke()` would return the object that is being returned by the method that is being returned by the method that is reflected. But seems it doesn't work.. I debugged my code ans seems it doesn't return anything. What I doing wrong? Please tell me if I did something wrong

Comment: Most of your code didn't even compile due to mistakes with class names/constructors. Also: "writeline" is not a method for "System.out".
Solving those errors before asking your question would save time to the people who might (want to) help you.

Comment: thank you I wasn't in front of my IDE... thank you

Comment: I made a mistake editting: I wrote `target.Foo();` instead of `target.Goo();`, and now I can't change correct it. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably need to cast `target` object to `foo type`.

```
((foo)target).goo();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a class's method within a variable, you should declare that variable of that class:

```
Foo target = (Foo) method.invoke(obj, arr); // And do some casting.
target.goo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides the missing cast in reflection (Test class), your Foo class had one error. Your code should rather look like this.

```
class Foo {
    private String str = ""; 

    public Foo(String str) {
        this.str = str; //You had str=this.str;
    }

    public void goo() {
        System.out.println(this.str);
    }
}

class Bar {
    public Foo met(String str) {
        return new Foo(str);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class cls = Class.forName("Bar");
        Bar obj = (Bar) cls.newInstance();
        Class[] types = { String.class };
        String[] arr = { "hello" };
        Method method = cls.getMethod("met", types);
        Foo target = (Foo) method.invoke(obj, arr);
        target.goo(); 
   }
}
```